# SSRS 3D Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart Offset and Depth Properties

Tags: reporting-services, charts, properties, 3d

I am using SSRS (on top of SQL Server 2014). I am making a 3D horizontal stacked bar chart, but there are some display properties that I cannot figure out, despite all information available.

[image: SSRS 3D Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart]

I Am wondering how/if the two measures in the chart above, a & b, can be set:

(a) The depth of the bar chart. Can I make this smaller? I want a much narrower bar.

(b) The offset of the chart from the axis. Is there a way to make the bar hug right up against the axis? Maybe I'm the only one, but when I look at the right extreme of the bar,I have trouble telling how close it falls to the 300 line due to this unnecessary offset.

Furthermore, does SSRS allow me to control things like the color rendering of the chart? Here is an example from another BI reporting tool:

[image: BIRT 3D Horizontal Stacked Bar]

This one has black outlines around all of the bars. Is SSRS capable of this? Mostly, I am just wondering if SSRS can make a chart that looks more like the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two can be easily changed.

To set the bar width and border colour, click on one of the bars then hit F4 to bring up the properties pane.

In the properties, expand `Custom Attributes` and set the point width to something smaller, say 0.2 and set the border colour and style to your choosing.

Here's a screen-grab of the properties to give a nice garish red border and smaller bars.

[image: Properties Pane]

To set the bars against the base, go to the horizontal (or vertical if you want to change this too) axis properties and set `Side Margins` to `Disabled`.

This gives this output...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has helped tremendously. I cannot find `Side Margins` in the list of attributes, but I did find `Margin` as a property under `Scale` when I select the axis, and I set it to `False`, and it appears to do what I need it to.
Also, making the `Point Width` on the horizontal bars seems to affect their height rather than their depth. Are you experiencing the same behavior? I am attempting to keep their height the same while making them less deep (to appear more narrow, from a front-to-back perspective).